# System.AccessViolationException on avcodec_open2 using FFMpeg.AutoGen

Tags: c#, video, ffmpeg, nvidia, autogen

I am using FFMpeg.AutoGen (v6.0.0.2) with hwencode support for Nvidia cards, and in few devices (for example on NVIDIA GeForce MX350) when I am doing fffmpeg.avcodec_open2 I got the following ffmpeg message in logs:

```
[h264_nvenc @ 000001f473fcc480] OpenEncodeSessionEx failed: unsupported device (2): (no details)
```

And then it crashes with the following crash:

```
Fatal error. System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
   at FFmpeg.AutoGen.DynamicallyLoadedBindings+<>c.<Initialize>b__2_494(FFmpeg.AutoGen.AVCodecContext*, FFmpeg.AutoGen.AVCodec*, FFmpeg.AutoGen.AVDictionary**)
   at FFmpeg.AutoGen.ffmpeg.avcodec_open2(FFmpeg.AutoGen.AVCodecContext*, FFmpeg.AutoGen.AVCodec*, FFmpeg.AutoGen.AVDictionary**)
   at GraphicsCheck.FfmpegChecker.StartEncoder(Omni.Platforms.Windows.Services.AV.CodecInfo, Int32, Int32, Int32)
   at GraphicsCheck.FfmpegChecker.CheckConfig(CodecConfig)
   at Program.<Main>$(System.String[])
```

I created [a sample app](https://github.com/Ruslan-B/FFmpeg.AutoGen/files/11654095/GraphicsCheck.zip) to demo this issue. And following the path of the calls..

1. That happens at [nvenc_open_session](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/n6.0/libavcodec/nvenc.c#L398) and i[s called here](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/n6.0/libavcodec/nvenc.c#L650)
2. That would cause going to [fail2 routine](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/n6.0/libavcodec/nvenc.c#L673), which is this one:

```
fail2:
    CHECK_CU(dl_fn->cuda_dl->cuCtxDestroy(ctx->cu_context_internal));
    ctx->cu_context_internal = NULL;
```

3. ctx->cu_context_internal comes from ([in same method](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/n6.0/libavcodec/nvenc.c#L640)) then I suppose it was created properly (as otherwise wouldn't continue).

```
    ret = CHECK_CU(dl_fn->cuda_dl->cuCtxCreate(&ctx->cu_context_internal, 0, cu_device));
    if (ret < 0)
        goto fail;
```

4. ctx in that method is the priv_data of AVCodecContext as we can see [here](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/n6.0/libavcodec/nvenc.c#L606):

```
static av_cold int nvenc_check_device(AVCodecContext *avctx, int idx)
{
    NvencContext *ctx = avctx->priv_data;
```

5. Also the act of printing the error message, on [nvenc_print_error](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/n6.0/libavcodec/nvenc.c#L146), is interacting with context.

```
static int nvenc_print_error(AVCodecContext *avctx, NVENCSTATUS err,
                             const char *error_string)
{
    const char *desc;
    const char *details = "(no details)";
    int ret = nvenc_map_error(err, &desc);

#ifdef NVENC_HAVE_GETLASTERRORSTRING
    NvencContext *ctx = avctx->priv_data;
    NV_ENCODE_API_FUNCTION_LIST *p_nvenc = &ctx->nvenc_dload_funcs.nvenc_funcs;

    if (p_nvenc && ctx->nvencoder)
        details = p_nvenc->nvEncGetLastErrorString(ctx->nvencoder);
#endif

    av_log(avctx, AV_LOG_ERROR, "%s: %s (%d): %s\n", error_string, desc, err, details);

    return ret;
}
```

6. av_log is executed as we can see the error message on logs then the other lines shouldn't be a problem.
7. Seeing the other calls, when nvenc_check_device fails the error is going up to [nvenc_check_device -> nvenc_setup_device](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/n6.0/libavcodec/nvenc.c#L778) but we aren't seeing more logs then the issue may be on nvenc_check_device on fail2 routine or on nvenc_print_error

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Are you sure this is C#??

Comment: @Charlieface FFMpeg.AutoGen is a wrapper over native C++ ffmpeg library, System.AccessViolationException is the crash I am getting at C# level and the insights I set are from ffmpeg just in case it helps to know what is happening